# Gremlin Repeat Until Returning Edges on path()

Tags: apache, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am trying to come up with a gremlin query to find who is an employee and knows "Jack". I am interested as well on the path together with the edges to understand why they know each other

Here the representation of it
[image]

Here is the query I come up with but no luck with getting the edges.

```
g.V().has('isSSEmployee',true).repeat(both().simplePath()).until(has('name','Jack')).path().limit(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have edges returned in the path result you need to specifically reference them in the query. Something like this:

```
g.V().has('isSSEmployee',true).repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath()).until(has('name','Jack')).path().limit(10)
```

Hope that helps.
Kelvin